# How to reference a NavigationSubform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to apply a filter to NavigationSubform "frmVariants". The Navigation form is named "NavigationForm".  How to correctly refence the form from another form "Search", outside the Navigation form?

Before I attached "frmVariants" to "NavigationForm" my code was:

```
[Forms]![frmVariants].Filter = Criteria
[Forms]![frmVariants].FilterOn = True
```

However, after I've attached it, I'm not sure how to reference it correctly.

Also, I'm trying to run queries on in listbox in "Search" pop up form that references a control "txtCurrentRun" on frmVariants and that's not working either.

The only solution that might work if I somehow passed the value of txtCurrent to a global variable and passed it to pop-up form? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your parent form name was, but you should be able to do it by using

```
Forms![main form name]![subform control name].Form![control name]
```

There's also a very good online [article from mvps.org](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) with many examples that might fit your situations